# References for trivial extension of a ring by a module

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation, noetherian

I'm reading a note having this definition: Let $R$ be a ring amd $M$ an $R$-module. The trivial extension of $R$ by $M$, written by $R\ltimes M$, is the $R$-algebra formed by endowing the direct sum $R\oplus M$ with the multiplication:
$$(r,m)(s,n)=(rs,rn+sm).$$

Can you give me some references about this definition so that I can understand it better? This note also states some facts like if $R$ is Noetherian and $M$ is finitely generated then $R\ltimes M$ is Noetherian and has the same dimension as $R$. To prove these facts myself, I need to understand the ring structure on it, but I'm having some troubles understand its ideals and prime ideals.

Comment: The multiplication should be $(r,m)(s,n)=(rs,rn+sm)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good reference is the survey "Idealization of a module" by Anderson and Winders, which you can find [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-commutative-algebra/volume-1/issue-1/Idealization-of-a-Module/10.1216/JCA-2009-1-1-3.full) (idealization is another name for trivial extension). The results you need are proved in Proposition 2.2 and Theorem 3.2.